# Java Hibernate JPQL Query (Aggregate Function: count)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpql

During a join I get the following Table (example):

```
+----------+----------+
| Hostname | Severity |
+----------+----------+
| host1    |   high   |
| host2    |  medium  |
| host1    |   high   |
| host2    |   low    |
| host1    |   low    |
| host2    |   low    |
| host1    |   low    |
| host2    |   high   |
| host1    |   high   |
| host2    |   high   |
+----------+----------+
```

Is it possible to create I JPQL query where I get the following result:

```
+----------+------+--------+-----+
| Hostname | high | medium | low |
+----------+------+--------+-----+
| host1    |  3   |   0    |  2  |
| host2    |  2   |   1    |  2  |
+----------+------+--------+-----+
```

I tried with `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` but I got something like that:

```
host1,high,3
host1,medium,0
host1,low,2
```

etc...

BR, Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard sql query would look like this - I'm not sure what effort is required to the API you are using, but its a pretty straight-forward group by with case logic.

```
select hostname, 
  sum(case when severity = 'high' then 1 else 0 end) as high,
  sum(case when severity = 'medium' then 1 else 0 end) as medium,
  sum(case when severity = 'low' then 1 else 0 end) as low
from
  Table
group by
  hostname
order by
  hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your result looks fine, it's just one row per "cell".

If you want to have a column per `Severity` entry, you'd have to use subselects, which is not worth the hassle, IMO. Just read the rows you get and convert them into the matrix format manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't want to do that additionally. The above works and I can get the wantet result in a single query.